# Emulator need to be close automatically after run the script in windows

Tags: java, android, eclipse, appium

After the execution of automated test script using Appium on windows, the emulator should be closed automatically. Please help me.

```
 public void setUp (String p) throws MalformedURLException,InterruptedException
 {

 DesiredCapabilities capabilities= new DesiredCapabilities();
 capabilities.setCapability(CapabilityType.BROWSER_NAME,Browser);
 capabilities.setCapability(CapabilityType.VERSION,version);
 capabilities.setCapability(CapabilityType.PLATFORM,Platform);
 capabilities.setCapability("platformName","Android");
 capabilities.setCapability("udid","emulator-"+p);
 capabilities.setCapability("avd",""+p);

 capabilities.setCapability("devices","Android");

 capabilities.setCapability("deviceName","");
 Thread.sleep(60000);
 capabilities.setCapability("appPackage", "com.android.browser");
 capabilities.setCapability("appActivity",   "com.android.browser.BrowserActivity");

 driver=new RemoteWebDriver(new URL("http://127.0.0.1:4723/wd/hub"),   capabilities);
 }
```

Comment: You'll need to add more details so people can understand what you are trying to do and whatever errors you are getting.

Comment: emulator opening properly but we need to close the emulator by the script automatically

Comment: you can quit the app but i don't think you can quit the emulator by using appium

Answer (score 1):

To the best of my knowledge, Appium does not let you to close the running emulator instance. One quick and easy way to work around this is to find the process and kill it.

However, what I would suggest doing is to use the adb option to kill the emulator

Add this as the last line after tearing down the driver with driver.quit().

```
Runtime.getRuntime().exec("adb -s emulator-5554 emu kill");
```

Please note that emulator-xxxx needs to be replaced with whatever port you're running it on.

Comment: It works in ubuntu,not in windows

Comment: Are you sure? Although I've never used it on windows, I'm fairly certain that adb can be accessed from the cmd line in Windows.

Comment: I cannot access avd from the command line in windows.

Comment: Its late but... `adb emu kill` worked in windows too.